# In net 5, when binding from body, how to specify that all properties must be present?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, model-validation, validationattribute

Attributes like BindRequired make an action parameter to be required, even the usual model validation [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#top-level-node-validation) can be applied. How can you make all properties from a class be required to be present in the request body?

Comment: You could try to create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0), then using the following code to apply ModelBinding Attribute on Action method: `public IActionResult Index([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))]User u)  
`, check [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have access to change the class: decorate all the properties with`[Required]` or `[BindRequired]`.

If you don't, you should make a DTO (Data Transfer Object) for that class and apply `[Required]` or `[BindRequired]` attributes.

Comment: I already considered this approach, isn't there any other just working with the action parameters?

Comment: So make a class-level validation class. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0